# stories .mdx doesn't load properly in react storybook project

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am working on a storybook project and here is a story of a sample component (sample.stories.mdx):

```
import Sample from './index';
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';
import { Canvas, Meta, Story, ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

<Meta title='Molecules/Sample' component={Sample} />

export const Template = (props) => <Sample {...props} />;

export const props = {
  label: 'Sample',
  children: 'Click me'
};

<Canvas>
  <Story name='Default' args={props}>
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable story='Default' />
```

But every time I start the project, it shows the following error:

```
./components/molecules/Sample/Sample.stories.mdx: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:64)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file
```

Can anyone help? Is this mdx file correct?

Thanks in advance.